# PDE Evans Chapter 7 problem 16

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Problem 16 of chapter 7 states

> Use problem 15 to prove that if $u$ is the semigroup solution in $X=L^2(U)$ of
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{rl}
> u_t - \Delta u =0 & \text{in } U_T \\
> u=0 & \text{on } \partial U \times [0,T] \\
> u=g & \text{on } U \times \{t=0\},
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   with $g \in C_c^{\infty}(U)$, then $u(\cdot,t) \in C^{\infty}(U)$
>   for each $0\leq t\leq T$.

Problem 15 states

> Let $\{S(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ be a contraction semigroup on X, with generator $A$.
>   Inductively define $D(A^k):= \{ u \in D(A^{k-1}) \textbf{ | }  A^{k-1}u \in D(A)\}$ $(k=2,\dots)$. Show that if $u \in D(A^k)$ for some $k$, then
>   $S(t) u \in D(A^k)$ for each $t \geq 0$.

For problem 15 I didn't need the contraction property for this.

My question is how to use this in the Problem 16.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, you can use 15 to be sure that $S(t)u\in L^2$. Then you may test
$$
S(t)u=u+\int_0^t\Delta S(s)u ds
$$
against $S(t)u$. Then you observe that 
$$
\int_0^t\|\nabla S(s)u\|_{L^2}^2ds<\infty
$$
Then you have that 
$$
\|\nabla S(s)u\|_{L^2}^2ds<\infty\,a.e.
$$
Pick one of these time points and redo everything. Then you finally get that 
$$
S(t)u\in H^s,\forall s\geq0
$$